# MAPIE - Model Agnostic Prediction Interval Estimator

Tags: python-3.x

Attempts to obtain confidence intervals for the GradientBoostingRegressor model. I use the MAPIE library for this purpose.

When I try to compile the code I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4e4ff6ae4c27> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 from mapie.regression import MapieQuantileRegressor
      9 
---> 10 Model = GradientBoostingRegressor(
     11     n_estimators = 500,
     12     max_depth = 4,

TypeError: GradientBoostingRegressor.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'objective'
```

Below is the program code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mapie.regression import MapieQuantileRegressor

Model = GradientBoostingRegressor(
    n_estimators = 500,
    max_depth = 4,
    min_samples_split = 5,
    learning_rate = 0.01,
    objective = 'quantile',
    loss = "squared_error",
)

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=5000, n_features=1, noise=20, random_state=59)
X_train, X_tmp,  y_train, y_tmp  = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=2000, random_state=42)
X_calib, X_test, y_calib, y_test = train_test_split(X_tmp, y_tmp, test_size=1000, random_state=42)

alpha = 0.1
mapie = MapieQuantileRegressor(estimator=Model, cv="split", alpha=alpha)
mapie.fit(X_train, y_train, X_calib=X_calib, y_calib=y_calib)
y_pred, y_pis = mapie.predict(X_test)
```